# How to hide/ change color of LWC outline to blend with the background

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

I have created three LWCs as shown in the image. I want the borders/blue outline to blend in with the background so one cannot tell they are different components.

How can I do that?

For some reason the component with the map does not show the outline which is what I want.

The code for the map has a styling but when I put it on the other component it doesn't do the same.

the component on the left is as shown. I have not used slds-box anywhere.

[image: with borders]

```
<template>
    
        <div class="slds-p-around_medium" >
            <p >Maps content</p>
            <lightning-map
                map-markers={mapMarkers}>
            </lightning-map>     
        </div>
</template>
```

I am trying to replicate the image below. [image: sample]

Comment: I assume you have used 'slds-box' to get the borders around the components.
you can use a custom css class and set the border color to a shade of gray - #cbcbcb might work. 
Or you can try using the box shadow property - box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #cbcbcbcb; which will create a light gray outline around the components which will be less noticeable.

Comment: I haven't used slds box. just a lightning card. I have updated the code to show the left component.

Answer (score 1):

I got it! I had used the lightning card which was adding a border. After removing it, the outline is gone.